# Memory Leak in TouchMXL?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, touchxml

I'm using TouchXML to parse an XML-stream the following way:

```
CXMLDocument *parser = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:responseString options:0 error:nil];
[responseString release];

// array holding all the nodes
NSArray *directionNodes = [parser nodesForXPath:@"//direction" error:nil];
NSArray *linieNodes = [parser nodesForXPath:@"//route" error:nil];
NSArray *timeNodes = [parser nodesForXPath:@"//time" error:nil];

    for (int i = 0; i < [directionNodes count]; i++) {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        CXMLElement *direction = [directionNodes objectAtIndex:i];
        CXMLElement *route = [linieNodes objectAtIndex:i];
        CXMLElement *time = [timeNodes objectAtIndex:i];

        // if rows are empty, stop it
        if ([[direction stringValue] isEqualToString:@""]) {
            break;
        }

        AbfahrtszeitResult *result = [[AbfahrtszeitResult alloc] init];
        [result setLinie:[route stringValue]];
        [result setZiel:[direction stringValue]];
        [result setZeit:[time stringValue]];

        [mutableAbfahrten addObject:result];
        [result release];
        [pool release];
    }
```

Now, I always get a memory leak in the "stringValue"-line... am I doing something wrong or is it TouchXML?

Thanks a lot,

Stefan

```
-(NSString *) linie {
return linie;
}

- (void) setLinie:(NSString *)textValue {
    [textValue retain];
    [linie release];
    linie = textValue;
}

-(NSString *) ziel {
    return ziel;
}

-(void) setZiel:(NSString *)textValue {
    [textValue retain];
    [ziel release];
ziel = textValue;
}

-(NSString *) zeit {
return zeit;
}

-(void) setZeit:(NSString *)textValue {
    [textValue retain];
    [zeit release];
zeit = textValue;
}

+ (NSString *) cleanUpString:(NSString *) cleanme {
NSMutableString *tempString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:cleanme];
[tempString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp;" withString:@" " options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [tempString length])];
[tempString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp" withString:@" " options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [tempString length])];

return [tempString autorelease];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least one leak when `[[direction stringValue] isEqualToString:@""]` is true as you break out of the for loop without releasing your AutoreleasePool.  Beyond that, we'd need to see the implementation of your `AbfahrtszeitResult` class to see how your `Linie` setter is defined.

Comment: hi,

i added the implementation of Abfahrtszeitresult (the getters and setters).

You can ignore the NSAutoreleasePool - of course that's a mistake I make, but the leak was there before I introduced the pool.